# Change DataGridView connection and query on another form based on selection c#

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I've been trying to find an answer for this and I'm completely lost.
I have an application that starts with a logon screen, after the client is logged on, it opens an MDI Form in which I have some items on a menu strip. One of them are assets (which is what the app will be used for), and the assets menu has a drop down with different assets to select, PC's, software etc.

When you click on PC's, another window opens within the MDI Form that has a DataGridView on it. And it works great but, I don't want to create a window for each and every connection or table in my databases, I feel this is bad practice.

So what I want is, to be able to change the DGV based on the asset selection, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to do this. I've been trying to pass parameters from one form to the other but the I just get different errors etc.

Can you guys please point me in the right direction? I am new to visual studio etc and want to learn these things, so I'm not asking for freebies so to speak, just what the logic should look like more or less.

Thanx!!

[image]
[image: DGV]

Comment: bro, Please share the Code you are using so we can see what errors are you facing!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have code for what I'm trying to do because I have no idea what the logic should look like.

I'm still trying wrap my head around how two forms communicate in a way I need.
I'm used having variables in a loop and when they change values the result changes. But in visual studio everything needs to be called which makes it a bit difficult for a rookie like me.

I did try sending sql commands via variables, but read that, that is a very bad idea.

I just want the DGV to change the data its showing based on a button selection.